# Export function of ShellExection to DLL delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, shellexecute

How do I export this function ExecuteFile from ShellExecute to a DLL. It does not work if I call via DLL. However if I use ShellExecution directly in the project it works

```
procedure ExecuteFile(FileName:WideString);stdcall;
begin
  ShellExecute(0,nil,PChar(FileName),nil,nil,SW_NORMAL);
end;

procedure ExecuteFile(FileName:WideString);stdcall; external 'my.dll';
```

Comment: What specifically does *does not work* mean? We can't see your screen from here. In what way **specifically** does it **not work**?

Comment: It looks like you're confused between `external` and `exports`.

Comment: Also, what version of Delphi are you using? `ExecuteFile()` takes a `WideString` (why?) as input, so you should be calling `ShellExecuteW()` with `PWideChar` to match. `ShellExecute()` does not map to `ShellExecuteW()`, and `PChar` does not map to `PWideChar`, unless you are using Delphi 2009+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate projects, one for the DLL itself, and one for the project that uses the DLL.

In the DLL project, you use `exports`, eg:

```
library my;

uses
  Shellapi;

{$R *.res}

procedure ExecuteFile(FileName: WideString); stdcall;
begin
  ShellExecuteW(0, nil, PWideChar(FileName), nil, nil, SW_NORMAL);
end;

exports
  ExecuteFile;

begin
end.
```

Then, in the consuming project, you use an `external` declaration to import the function from the DLL, eg:

```
procedure ExecuteFile(FileName: WideString); stdcall; external 'my.dll';
```

Then the project can call `ExecuteFile()` like any other function, eg:

```
ExecuteFile('filename');
```

Just make sure the exporting DLL is:

1. located somewhere on the [OS's search path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx), preferably in the same folder as the consuming app.
2. compiled to use the same bitness (32bit or 64bit) as the consuming project.

Otherwise, it won't load correctly.

Comment: It worked. He was unaware of this other function. I am using export pair to a DLL from an SDK that I am designing. Thank you!